# Subclassed UIView for custom drawing, context is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I would like to have a class for rendering simple charts inside of it (no complex stuff). My idea is/was to:

- Sublass an `UIView` --> lets call it `Grapher`
- Implement all my methods in it (`drawBarGraph`, `drawProgressBar`, `drawLineGraph`)
- Include it in the desired view controller, create an instance of `Grapher`, call the desired method
- Add that instance as a subview to my main view.

Lets jump into some code since im not sure how to explain this. Here is the `grapher.h`:

```
@interface Grapher : UIView
{
    CGContextRef context; //for passing it in via constructor

    //UIColor *backgroundColor;
    UIColor *graphColor; //foreground color
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frm inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx;

- (void)setGraphColor:(UIColor*)color;

- (void)drawHistogramWithItems:(NSArray*)items;
//- (void)drawLineChartWithItems:(NSArray*)items;
- (void)drawProgressLineWithPercentage:(float)percent;
```

And the corresponding `grapher.m`:

```
@implementation Grapher

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frm inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frm];
    if (self)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma Mark main draw methods

- (void)drawHistogramWithItems:(NSArray *)items
{
    //[backgroundColor set];
    //UIRectFill(frame);
    [graphColor set];

    int itemWidth = 20;

    if (items.count == 0) return;

    float max = -1;
    for (SFGraphItem *item in items)
        if (item.value > max)
            max = item.value;

    float spacing = (frame.size.width - (itemWidth * items.count)) / (items.count + 1);
    float xPos = spacing;

    for (int i = 0; i < items.count; i++)
    {
        CGFloat itemHeight = ((SFGraphItem*)[items objectAtIndex:i]).value / max * frame.size.height;
        CGRect bar = CGRectMake(xPos, frame.origin.y + frame.size.height - itemHeight, itemWidth, itemHeight);
        CGContextAddRect(context, bar);
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
        xPos += spacing + itemWidth;
    }

}

- (void)drawProgressLineWithPercentage:(float)percent
{
    //[backgroundColor set];
    //UIRectFill(frame);
    [graphColor set];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width / 100 * percent, frame.size.height));
}

#pragma Mark setters/getters

- (void)setGraphColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    graphColor = color;
}

@end
```

Nice and simple. If I subclass it as a `NSObject` then subclass `UIView` in another file (lets call it `GraphArea`), override `drawRect` there, `alloc-init` the `Grapher` and pass the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` in it works just fine.

But I do not want a "middle-view" for this. I would like to subclass `UIView` as `Grapher` and do it like this:

```
Grapher *graph = [[Grapher alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 65, winSize.width - 10, 20)]; //some random frame
[graph setGraphColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[graph drawProgressLineWithPercentage:50];
graph.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

[someview addSubview:graph];
```

If I call the constructor with `CGContextRef` or this one and try to get the context there it is always null. How to pass in current context? What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?
If I explained it too sloppy let me know and I will try harder.

Cheers, Jan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

If I understand you correctly, you're misunderstanding what a view does.

A view manages its own drawing in its own space. You don't give it a context, you let it create or set up a context as necessary and draw in its own coordinate system. It sounds like you're trying to create a view that draws in another view's context, and I can't think of a single good reason for doing that. From the docs for UIView, right up there at the top of the page:

> The UIView class defines a rectangular area on the screen and the
>   interfaces for managing the content in that area. At runtime, a view
>   object handles the rendering of any content in its area and also
>   handles any interactions with that content.

If you're trying to create a view that simply draws something in another view, you're doing it wrong. It might be fine to encapsulate your drawing methods in some class and use an instance of that class to draw a graph in a view, but if that's what you want you shouldn't make that class a subclass of UIView.

> If I subclass it as a NSObject then subclass UIView in another file
>   (lets call it GraphArea), override drawRect there, alloc-init the
>   Grapher and pass the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() in it works just
>   fine.

It's fine to subclass UIView, but it's not okay for that UIView subclass to try to draw in some other view's space. If you want to create a graph that you can add as content to some other view, but not make the graph a view of its own, then you might look into CALayer instead. With a layer, you can override `-drawInContext:` to do your drawing. You can create layers and add them to an existing view. The drawing system will composite your layer with the view's other layers.

Comment: I would like an rectangular area on which I could render a graph. So I tried to subclass an UIView and implement methods from above. How should I tackle this problem then? Any source would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Majster I don't see a `-drawRect:` method in your `Grapher` class. `-drawRect:` is the method that will be called when the view needs to be rendered, so it's where you should put your drawing code. You can leave your existing methods and just add a `-drawRect:` that makes appropriate calls to them. The graphics context will already be set up for you when `-drawRect:` is called, so you don't have to worry about getting or setting up a context.

Comment: @Majster Also, the way you want to use it is just slightly off. When you create a view, you don't tell the view to draw something, you just tell it *how* to draw something. Let the view hierarchy take care of *when* to do the drawing. Just give the view all the information it needs to draw, and trust that `-drawRect:` will be called when the time is right.

Comment: I see, definitely makes stuff clearer to me. Just how do I tell my view what to draw? Set some state inside those methods and call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` and check the state inside `drawRect` or is there a more clever way?

Comment: Right. You can set some state in the view, as when you tell a label what text to display and what font to use, or when you tell an image view what image to show. Or, you can tell the view where to get the data it needs. For example, UITableView and UICollectionView each use delegate and data source objects to get what they need, so you don't have to load all your data into a table before the table can draw, and the table only asks for as much information as it needs.